# spring DispatcherServlet context inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

Typically there is one `ApplicationContext` (parent) and 0..n `DispatcherServlets` (children). Is it also possible to **have a`DispatcherServlet` that has another `DispatcherServle`t as parent context** which has the `ApplicationContext` as parent? As I understood, beans can be resolved transitively so it should be possible to access the application context.

I don't want to put the shared beans into the `ApplicationContext` because they must not be exposed to other `DispatcherServlet` - with one exception.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to?

Comment: i have a traditional repository - service - controller architecture. I want to but another layer on top of the existing controller layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended the DispatcherServlet. Now it works perfectly!

```
public class ConfigurableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private String contextParent;

    /**
     * Initialize and publish the WebApplicationContext for this servlet.
     * <p>
     * Delegates to {@link #createWebApplicationContext} for actual creation of
     * the context. Can be overridden in subclasses.
     * 
     * @return the WebApplicationContext instance
     * @see #setContextClass
     * @see #setContextConfigLocation
     */
    protected WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext() {
        // No fixed context defined for this servlet - create a local one.
        WebApplicationContext parent = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext(),
                "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT." + getContextParent());
        WebApplicationContext wac = createWebApplicationContext(parent);

        // Publish the context as a servlet context attribute.
        String attrName = getServletContextAttributeName();
        getServletContext().setAttribute(attrName, wac);
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Published WebApplicationContext of servlet '" + getServletName() +
                        "' as ServletContext attribute with name [" + attrName + "]");
        }
        if(this.logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            this.logger.info(getServletName() + " is a child of " + parent.getDisplayName());
        }

        return wac;
    }

    public String getContextParent() {
        return contextParent;
    }

    public void setContextParent(String contextParent) {
        this.contextParent = contextParent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`HttpServletBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean.html) and [`FrameworkServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) it looks like you can do the following to make `bar` use context of `foo` as its own:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>...DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>...DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>foo-servlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: looks great, ill check it out!

Comment: Sadly it fails: "No WebApplicationContext found: initializer not registered?" Does it work for you?

Comment: It failed with "No WebApplicationContext found: initializer not registered?" But I found out that I have to prefix the contextAttribute with "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.". Now it is loaded correctly - but the "contextConfigLocation" is not evaulated (or for some other reason my context xml file is not loaded and therefore no controllers are started). Any idea?